# Delete rows where 5 or more columns have values less than 3

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a dataset of RNAseq from featureCounts which I have merged. I have 3 conditions with 3 replicates. I want to delete rows where 5 or more columns have values less than 3 of gene expression

Here is a sample of my dataset.

```
Gene_id. M1 M2 M3 W1 W2 W3 S1 S2 S3
ENSMUSG00000102693 18 4 5 8 0 2 1 0 0
ENSMUSG00000064842 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2
ENSMUSG00000051951 25 23 32 54 78 77 48 56 33
ENSMUSG00000102851 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
ENSMUSG00000103377 0 10 0 2 5 0 6 7 8
```

I would like to import this dataset for further DE analysis in another tool for analysis.

Comment: Thank you for providing sample input.   Now please add corresponding *output.*

Comment: I am looking for commands to enable me create an output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want

```
awk '{
        count=0
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i < 3) count++
        if (count < 5) print
     }'
```

For each line, set a counter to zero.
Then look at each field (column) other than the first (the Gene ID),
and, if it is less than 3, count it. 
Then, if the count is less than five, print the line. 
If five or more columns have values less than 3,
skip the line (i.e., delete it).

If you need to collapse this into a single line,
you must add semicolons (`;`) after the statements
(i.e., where the line breaks are in the above version):

```
awk '{ count=0; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i < 3) count++; if (count < 5) print; }'
```

Comment: this is the error message I get [lcoscoy@ln001 bin]$ awk '{count=0 for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i < 3) count++ if (count < 5) print}' RNA.txt                                                       
awk: cmd. line:1: {count=0 for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i < 3) count++ if (count < 5) print}
awk: cmd. line:1:          ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {count=0 for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if ($i < 3) count++ if (count < 5) print}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                    ^ syntax error

Comment: See edited answer.